# Finding an appropriate surjective map $f: S \to T$ such that the preimages satisfy closure under complements, unions, and intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Given a set $S$, let $\mathcal{E} \subset \mathcal{P}(S)$ such that (1) $S \in \mathcal{E}$, (2) if $A \in \mathcal{E}$ then $S - A \in \mathcal{E}$, (3) if $A,B \in \mathcal{E}$ then $A \cup B \in \mathcal{E}$ and $A \cap B \in \mathcal{E}$. Prove that if $S$ is finite then there is a set $T$ and a surjective map $f: S \to T$ such that $\mathcal{E} = \{f^{-1} (A) \mid A \subset T\}$. What happens if $S$ is infinite?

My first though was that the requirements for $\mathcal{E}$ sound a lot like the axioms for a sigma-field, but I don't think I have enough machinery to work with that. The other possibility I considered is that this is looking for a quotient map. Given a set $S$, I can define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S$ by $a \sim b$ if and only if $f(a) = f(b)$. Then $T = S/{\sim}$, the quotient of $S$ by $\sim$. Then $f: S \to T$ is certainly surjective. Given any $t \in S/{\sim}$, $t$ is nonempty by definition and I can pick one representation $s \in S$ for which $f(s) = t$. Now I define
$$
\mathcal{E} = \{f^{-1} (A) \mid A \subset S/{\sim} \}.
$$
A subset of $S/{\sim}$ could either be an equivalence class itself, in which case $f^{-1} (A)$ is just the set of representatives of that equivalence class or the equivalence class itself. If I take $A$ to consist of multiple such classes, then $f^{-1} (A)$ is a disjoint union of equivalence classes. To check each of the axioms: If I take $A = S/{\sim}$, we have $f^{-1} (S/{\sim}) = S$, so $S \in \mathcal{E}$. If $A \in \mathcal{E}$, then $A = f^{-1} (B)$ for some $B \subset S/{\sim}$. Taking $C = S/{\sim} - B$, we have $f^{-1} (C) = f^{-1} (S/{\sim} - B) = S - B$.

Is this on the right track? Any hints on how to proceed and comments on the above would be appreciated. I'm not even sure at this point rather I have the right $T$ or the right map.

Comment: The problem with your quotient map approach is that you are pretending you already have $f$ and are using it to define $\sim$. But you don't have an $f$. Instead you need to figure out what the equivalence relation $\sim$ should be and define $f$ as the map carrying each $s \in S$ to its equivalence class. What equivalence relation on $S$ can you define from $\mathcal E$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair That is an excellent point that I hadn't at all realized. The only thing I can think of is that $\mathcal{E}$ in some way partitions $S$ and I can define an equivalence relation on $S$ to the effect of $a \sim b$ if $a,b$ live in some some set $A \subset \mathcal{E}$.

Comment: Not "some" set. Consider how what fails if you just take the equivalance to be "=", and $f$ is the identity function. What do you need to correct that?

Comment: Ok, so if the equivalence is equality, then $S/{\sim}$ is a collection of singletons. The identity function wouldn't make sense there because I'd be mapping elements $s$ to singleton sets $\{s\}$. I must be missing something, because I don't think that's what you had in mind.

Comment: That is exactly what I had in mind - though you can forgo the equivalence relation altogether here, identifying $\{s\}$ with just $s$, which makes $f$ the identity function, and $S/=$ to be just $S$. Note that I said this would FAIL to provide what you need. The point, though, is to see exactly where it fails. Why is $\mathcal E \ne \mathcal P(S)$? What sets can exist in $\mathcal P(S)$ that are not in $\mathcal E$, given the restrictions on that collection? This will guide you in finding the equivalence relation definable from $\mathcal E$ that does work.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I'm a bit stumped unfortunately. Do you by any chance have another hint? It seems that I do ned to define some sort of equivalence relation/quotient set and $f$ is just the canonical quotient map for that equivalence relation, but I can't think of an equivalence relation corresponding to $\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: If $\mathcal E$ distinguishes between two points $a,b$ of $S$, then you would not want them equivalent. But if $\mathcal E$ does not not ever distinguish between them ...

Comment: What do you mean by distinguishes between them? That $a \not \sim b$? I can't tie this back to the definition of $\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: Why would I say "if $a \not\sim b$, then you would not want $a\sim b$"? That is a pointless statement, and I clearly was talking about $\mathcal E$, not $\sim$ anyway. $\mathcal E$ is a collection of sets. $a, b$ are two points in some of the sets in that collection. So what *reasonable* interpretation could be put to the idea that a collection of sets of points distinguishes between two points. "Distinguishes" is going to mean "treats them differently" vs treating them exactly the same. There is only one relation between sets and their elements to examine here,

Comment: I'm going to have to think about this a bit more, as I'm still very stumped. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The relation is $a \sim b$ if and only if for all $E \in \mathcal E, a \in E \iff b \in E$. All the sets in $\mathcal E$ either contain both, or neither. It makes no distinction between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair This makes much more sense. Does the argument require that $S$ is finite, though? The problem statement makes a distinction, but it doesn't seem to me that it matters.

Comment: Try to prove that the relation I gave you actually works. That is, $\mathcal E = \{f^{-1}(A) \mid A \subset S/\sim\}$